# Moves API Notifications: hash mismatch specific users

Tags: json, node.js, hash, hmacsha1

Our data aggregation service (Consume) is utilising the [Moves API Storyline Notifications](https://dev.moves-app.com/docs/api_notifications) and we are verifying the hash provided from Moves with our own generated by following the documentation. We have several users testing the service and most user's hash matches the signature (hash) of the Moves request. However, some users's notifications result in an mismatch in hashes. At Moves's Google Groups an issue of [JSON.parse()](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/moves-api/JSON.parse/moves-api/zFNjdhco5wg/zYnox_2AGAAJ) limitations in the length of userId is described but all userIds, in our case, are of equal length.

Below the function that verifies the hash: (I kept the console.log()s in the code to show what parameters are checked by us)

```
function verifyMovesHash(req, res) {
  let obj = JSON.stringify(req.body) + req.get('x-moves-timestamp') + req.get('x-moves-nonce')
  console.log('Obj Moves', obj)
  console.log('Moves headers', req.headers)
  let hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', '<CLIENT SECRET>').update(obj).digest('base64')
  console.log('HMAC Consume: ', hmac)
  console.log('Signature Moves: ', req.get('x-moves-signature'))

  if (hmac === req.get('x-moves-signature')) {
       signJWTandSendToCollect(req, res)
     } else {
       console.log('Moves hash-mismatch for user: ', req.body.userId)
     }
}
```

These are the logs for an unsuccessful hash comparison: (removed some identifiable information).

```
0|Consume  | Obj Moves {"userId":19017159843919340,"storylineUpdates":[{"reason":"DataUpload","startTime":"20161004T204819Z","endTime":"20161005T080135Z","lastSegmentType":"place","lastSegmentStartTime":"20161004T204819Z"},{"reason":"ActivityUpdate","startTime":"20161004T185932Z","endTime":"20161004T190703Z"}]}1475654517rBdrok/CNYZoInpMmKl2+A==
0|Consume  | Moves headers { 'x-real-ip': '54.209.46.155',
0|Consume  |   'x-forwarded-for': '54.209.46.155',
0|Consume  |   'x-nginx-proxy': 'true',
0|Consume  |   host: 'xxx',
0|Consume  |   connection: 'close',
0|Consume  |   'content-length': '289',
0|Consume  |   'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
0|Consume  |   'x-moves-signature': 'i5cRuKzEV0U/sRP18RIYn8wIaJ4=',
0|Consume  |   'x-moves-timestamp': '1475654517',
0|Consume  |   'x-moves-nonce': 'rBdrok/CNYZoInpMmKl2+A==',
0|Consume  |   accept: '*/*',
0|Consume  |   'user-agent': 'Moves API' }
0|Consume  | HMAC Consume:  0LBJaRrsG6JfLOd1QbEC6kG2PqI=
0|Consume  | Signature Moves:  i5cRuKzEV0U/sRP18RIYn8wIaJ4=
0|Consume  | Moves hash-mismatch for user:  19017159843919340
```

This is a successful one:

```
0|Consume  | Obj Moves {"userId":18926285641764670,"storylineUpdates":[{"reason":"DataUpload","startTime":"20161005T071824Z","endTime":"20161005T080056Z","lastSegmentType":"place","lastSegmentStartTime":"20161005T071824Z"}]}1475654470dBPm0K1YBFreuaSrE0Z1Tg==
0|Consume  | Moves headers { 'x-real-ip': '54.209.46.155',
0|Consume  |   'x-forwarded-for': '54.209.46.155',
0|Consume  |   'x-nginx-proxy': 'true',
0|Consume  |   host: 'xxx',
0|Consume  |   connection: 'close',
0|Consume  |   'content-length': '201',
0|Consume  |   'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
0|Consume  |   'x-moves-signature': 'XmJEVdRlREGjx1m1xm7mKi0pjxY=',
0|Consume  |   'x-moves-timestamp': '1475654470',
0|Consume  |   'x-moves-nonce': 'dBPm0K1YBFreuaSrE0Z1Tg==',
0|Consume  |   accept: '*/*',
0|Consume  |   'user-agent': 'Moves API' }
0|Consume  | HMAC Consume:  XmJEVdRlREGjx1m1xm7mKi0pjxY=
0|Consume  | Signature Moves:  XmJEVdRlREGjx1m1xm7mKi0pjxY=
```

The Obj Moves is the content for the hash as stated by Moves: (so body timestamp and nonce)

```
HMAC_SHA1(<your client secret>,<request body>|<timestamp>|<nonce>)
```

Through my reasoning the hashing function is correct because it does match frequently. Can anyone see why some hashes mismatch? If more information is needed let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the Moves API documentation is not up to date. In 2014 the v1 API was deprecated and they moved to 1.1 without updating their documentation properly. I'm assuming this will also fix my issues. Will edit the answer if this is not the case but for me the question is answered.

Comment: What was the update? Their API still has the old documentation, and I'm running into a similar issue with Human API.

Comment: For me it was an issue specifically with Moves. Perhaps ask a new question and post a link here? Happy to see if I can spot something :)

Comment: Thanks @martwetzels. I would post, but it's basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947400/hmac-sha1-digest-in-python.

Comment: Here's a link to a gist: https://gist.github.com/yangmillstheory/91d1424c421a2fdc1c3c669fccc0a709

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at it in a bit. Isn't the advantage of HumanAPI that you don't need to validate the authenticity and collect data directly from Moves in this case?

Comment: Yep, I should say that my problem is talking to Human API, not Moves API, but the nature of the problem is literally the same (signature verification does not match their documentation).

Comment: Well Just for checking. Do you always get a mismatch or one periodically? Can remember that the HMAC function sometimes benefits from a | separator.

Comment: I always get a mismatch. The `|` separator didn't work. Right now, my most likely theory is that it's similar to your case: the documentation is likely outdated.